# How to get all values of a specific key in a hash map of int[]

Tags: java

I have a following haspmap

```
private static Map<Integer, int[]> hm = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
m.put(1, new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
hm.put(96, new int[]{23,24,2,34,22});
hm.put(101, new int[]{123,11,22,34,5,4,7});
hm.put(96, new int[]{88,87,85,80,9,7,2,1});
hm.put(96, new int[]{110,123,11,22,34,33,29,4});
```

I want to get all value for say key 96,

```
if (hm.containsKey(route_ID)){ ... }
```

also then i want to iterate those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (hm.containsKey(route_ID)) {
  int[] values = hm.get(route_ID);
  for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    System.out.println(values[i]);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, even all other methods are working as well this one is easy to follow. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are iterable, so you can iterate over them using the `for (value : array)` syntax.

```
for (int value : hm.get(96)) {
  // ...
}
```

There is nothing built into `Map` or `HashMap` that supports anything like `containsValue(int[])` but that would very easy to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(hm.get(96) != null)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < hm.get(96).length ; i++)
          System.out.print("Value" + i + "=" + hm.get(96)[i] );
    }
```